# how to use an element width in a calculated value in css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, calc

I am using Bootstrap 3.

To center horizontally in the screen a `300px` wide button I use the following CSS code that uses `calc`:

```
.kiosk-form .centered
{
  margin-left: calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

In the code above, I would like to replace `150px`with something like `"element.width/2"` (to get rid of the hardcoded half-width in pixels) but I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Could anyone please suggest the solution?

As an alternative, is there another way to horizontally center a button?

Comment: a parent div with class ``row justify-content-center`` and then place the button inside the div. Button will be placed in the center horizontally

Comment: simply wrap the button in a div with the class ``text-center``

Comment: thanks for the comments, but i have little control on the DOM since the DOM is generated by a framework so I prefer to solve it with a CSS class.

Comment: Please don't abuse backticks for emphasis. They should be used for literal inline code and file names, not the names of languages or products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
.kiosk-form .centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, with this solution I achieve the desired result and I do not need to hardcore the half width in the CSS rules.